# How to stop tray notifications of past app crash every time I launch it?

Tags: windows-10, crash, taskbar, notification-area, report

Several days ago an app I was using crashed and I was offered the Win10 'send error report' dialogue box. I didn't want to so clicked the close button on the top right.

Ever since then, every time I start the app I get the following balloon notification:
"Error Reports, Some errors occurred in [the app] recently. Click here to send error reports now."

How do I stop this?

I do not want to send the report and am worried that if I just click it'll be sent straight away.

To be clear I also do not want to permanently stop these types of notifications from happening in the future.

All I want is for Windows10 to forget about this one specific past crash and stop reminding me of it every time the app is run.

EDIT The app was "Agent Ransack". A harddisk file searching utility. It works fine, I just want Win10 to forget that it crashed recently, and stop asking me to send crash reports.

Comment: We do not know what app, so there is not a lot of help to be offered. There is not harm in sending error reports as these are aggregated without personal information. Go to Start, Settings, Apps and look for your App. Click on Advanced Features and both Repair and Reset it. Close out, Restart and test.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got rid of the trey notifications by taking the plunge and just clicking on one.

Despite the threat of "Click here to send error reports now" it did not send them straight away, instead it took me to a list of pending error reports.

I right-clicked the list and selected "Delete all", then clicked "Other actions…" / "Close this window and never remind again"

No idea if that latter option has permanently disabled such tray notifications - I hope not - but at least I can now launch the app without getting a reminder of the crash from several days ago.